# What will cause presto raise error 'Partition metadata not available'?

Tags: hive, presto

I'm using presto + hive, and using a external table, feed data using hdfs web api.

the table is someting like

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `eventid` string,
    `group_id` string)
PARTITIONED BY (`dt` string, `appid` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','    
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/mytable'
```

I use pyhive to create partition each time before push data file to hdfs

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable 
    ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (dt='{dt}', appid='{appid}')
```

then use hdfs web api push data file to the location

```
/user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/mytable/dt={dt}/appid={appid}/data.csv
```

it works fine for almost all the time, but occasionally when i fire a query through presto, it just throw an exception 'Partition metadata not available'

the query is something like

```
select * 
from mytable
where dt='{dt}'
  and appid='{appid}'
  and eventid in ('...')
```

the whole error messages are

```
DatabaseError: {'message': 'Partition metadata not available', 'errorCode': 16777216, 'errorName': 'HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR', 'errorType': 'EXTERNAL', 'failureInfo': {'type': 'com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException', 'message': 'Partition metadata not available', 'suppressed': [], 'stack': ['com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveSplitManager.lambda$getPartitionMetadata$1(HiveSplitManager.java:200)', 'com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:799)', 'com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)', 'com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)', 'com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:548)', 'com.facebook.presto.hive.ConcurrentLazyQueue.poll(ConcurrentLazyQueue.java:37)', 'com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.loadSplits(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:219)', 'com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.access$300(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:78)', 'com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader$HiveSplitLoaderTask.process(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:179)', 'com.facebook.presto.hive.util.ResumableTasks.safeProcessTask(ResumableTasks.java:45)', 'com.facebook.presto.hive.util.ResumableTasks.lambda$submit$1(ResumableTasks.java:33)', 'io.airlift.concurrent.BoundedExecutor.drainQueue(BoundedExecutor.java:77)', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)', 'java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)']}}
```

the error won't repeat, just occasionally happens. i think (and tested as well), try to query a empty partition, or a non-exists partition, won't cause any trouble, it should just return empty. and i didn't delete any partition in the process.

I search the internet but didn't find any useful information about 'Partition metadata not available' error, so i turn to stackoverflow for help.

what will cause such kind of error? how to avoid it? or when i meet such error should i just retry the process?

Comment: That error message is not in the current code base, but looking at the old code, it happens when the Hive metastore does not return any data for a partition.  My guess is there is something wring with your Hive metastore (race condition), or another process deleted the partition while the query was running (Presto does not read all partitions up front and instead loads them as needed over the life of the query).

Comment: thanks @DainSundstrom, I will check my presto and hive version

Comment: my presto version is 0.151, its released at 2016.07. and i find a issue was fixed at 2016.11 (https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/5734), seems to be something relavent. so I really should upgrade prestodb. @DainSundstrom thanks again.